# regex question: independent position of words

Tags: regex

is it possible to define a regex pattern which checks eg. for 3 terms independent to their position in the main string?

eg. my string is something like `"click here to unsubscribe: http://www.url.com"`

the pattern should also work with `"http:// unsubscribe click"`

thx

Comment: Any particular reason it would have to be done with one regex?

Comment: It would be useful to know what language you're working in. Different programming languages support different regex syntaxes.

Comment: How are you using this regex? The answer will be very different depending on whether you're validating a short string, or searching for this string in a much larger text such as a web page.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). For example,

```
(?=.*click)(?=.*unsubscribe).*http
```

is a regex that will look ahead from the current position (without moving ahead) for `click`, then for `unsubscribe`,  then search normally for `http`.

Comment: That only works if both "click" and "unsubscribe" come *after* "http", which doesn't jibe with the OP's first example.

Comment: @Alan Moore: True. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

It's *possible*, but results in very complicated regexs, e.g.:

```
/(click.*unsubscribe|unsubscribe.*click)/
```

Basically, you would need to have a different regex section for each order. Not ideal. Better to just use multiple regexes, one for each term.

Comment: Or use "index" or equivalents three times.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using conditionals.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: Can you provide more detail? I don't see how conditionals will help.