# How to match regex pattern independent of position?

Tags: java, regex

I've the following code working, the purpose is to have only numbers with only one decimal point at max.

```
String text    =   "121.30"; 

String pattern = "^\\d+\\.{0,1}\\d+$";  

boolean matches = Pattern.matches(pattern, text);
```

What other regex could I use so as not to include the leading digit matching? I mean is it possible to match digit only once regardless of position with respect to decimal point?

Comment: Maybe `String pattern = "(?=\\.?\\d)\\d*\\.?\\d*";`?

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(text);`?

Comment: Try `^\\d+\\.\\d$` This part `\\.{0,1}` makes the dot optional.

Comment: try this one `^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,1})?$`

Comment: I found one relevant answer here, but I want to explore alternatives. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601793/regex-question-independent-position-of-words.

Comment: Does [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861852/how-to-match-regex-pattern-independent-of-position#comment92638213_52861852) work? It allows a single `.` among any amount of digits, at any location, and only matches a string that has at least 1 digit.

Comment: I see multiple digit matching which I want to avoid.

Comment: Are you asking for only answers such as: **32.1** or **56.7**, or **12345.6**   _and not_ **32.10**, **56.78**, **12345.67**?  Is that what you mean by "just one decimal place matches"?

Comment: yes, there can be only 0 or 1 decimal point.

Comment: "1234.66." shouldn't match as there are two decimal points. I believe it's better to check for multiple decimal points first and discard it if it has more than one and then do the pattern matching with only one 'd' and '.'